# step by step debugging objective c

Tags: objective-c

is there any way to see the step by step debugging of the code in objective C, like we use to do in Turbo C with the keyboard key of 'F7 / F8'. to see the line by line execution?

Answer (score 3):

Sure. If you're using XCode (ala 99.99999% of Objective C users), just set a breakpoint, and when hit, control GDB either with the normal stepwise commands, or with the little interface toolbar that appears at the top of the source window.

For keyboard shortcuts, [this guide](http://www.1729.us/xcode/Xcode%20Shortcuts.pdf) has as section called "Run".

Comment: hi, 
thanks for replying, but breakpoint will shows only the behavior of the particular piece of code in the porject. But what if i want to understand the step-by-step code i.e which funtion is calling what method or class and so on from start till end, is there possibilty for that?

Comment: When you add a break point, there is part of the debugging window that shows a trace of all the class/methods that were called to get to where the breakpoint was. (I find this very helpful, it shows what happened up until that point)

Comment: Jacob - almost, but not quite. You see the call stack, that shows you the nesting of functions that were called to get to the current location. You don't see a trace of all previous calls that were executed on the path to the current state.